# SQL Server: When @parm = -1 return all records

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need help with my query:

When I send to the query a parameter with the value -1, I would like to get all the records  (this parameter wont filter the results), otherwise filter according the value.

I was trying something like this:

```
WHERE  (StatusId = CASE WHEN @StatusId = - 1 
        THEN 
        @StatusId IS NULL 
        ELSE 
        StatusId = @StatusId   END)
```

Thanks.

Comment: 4 times the exactly same answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
where  @StatusId = -1 or @StatusId = StatusId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 WHERE StatusId = @StatusId OR @StatusId = -1
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this would just do the trick

```
Where (@StatusId = -1 or StatusId=@StatusId )
```